# Inject parameters to JSX components passed as props

Tags: react-native, properties, react-functional-component

It often happens that I have to render a list of items that take a component as property. For example, UI Kitten's components (most of them) take components passed as functions for the props `accessoryLeft` and `accessoryRight`.
However, in order to pass the source parameter to an `Image` component to render for these, I have to pass a render-time built function, which re-evaluates every time the component renders.

For example:

```
function renderItem({ item, index, separators }){
    return <ListItem
        title={item.name}
        description={item.descriptions}

        // this function
        accessoryLeft={(imageProps) => {
            return <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} />;
        }}
    />;
}

function keyExtractor(item){ return `${item.id}`; }

function SomeList(props){
    return <List
        data={props.itemsList}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={renderItem}
    />;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow to optimize this? The image property of the renderedItem never changes, but a new function is passed to `accessoryLeft` and it is re-rendered every time, which causes flickering and slow load times...

Also, in this case, the `key` prop on the `<Image />` component does not help because a new function is rebuilt on each re-render.

Comment: Have you tried [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) or [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)?